# Blue Prism string format / validation

Tags: blueprism

I have a problem where I need to have some exception handling for some data that I will put into a excel report. The DataItem "Personal Identity Code" can be invalid; It must always be 11 characters long and its format should be DDMMYYSNNNX,
where DD = day, MM = month, YY = year, S = Either ‘A’ or ‘-‘, NNN = number, X = Letter or number
Examples: 310199-111K, 011206A2222

I want to somehow check this / validate the format before it will be processed from the queue (so I can throw an Business Exception). Is there some clever way to set this up? I was thinking about maybe a regex in combination with something?

**Edit:**

**This is how my process page look like with the solution:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate that kind of input I'd do two validations:

a) regex to check if it matches the expected format

Example regex could be this one:

```
\d{6}[A-]\d{3}[\d,a-z,A-Z]
```

or more strict one:

```
^\d{6}[A-]\d{3}[\d,a-z,A-Z]$
```

B) check if date at the start of the string is valid (e.g. no 30th of February, or 95th of 25th month).

I'd try to use calculation stage MakeDate() function in combination with Left() and Mid() functions. If the date is incorrect, then the BluePrism will throw an error "Unable to convert the 3 supplied parameters to a date"

Comment: That helped alot, i used the ^\d{6}[A-]\d{3}[\d,a-z,A-Z]$ in a calculation stage, then a decision stage to see if it's matched. Then i validate the dates in a multi calc stage and store it in 3 data items. Then i validate the stored data items in a decision stage with this "IsDate([Year] & "-" & [Month] & "-" & [Day])" to throw an Business Exception or move along :)

Comment: Updated my question with the process page